# How can I use a 1-1 mapping on the same table in Entity Framework database first?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, parent-child

I have a situation where I have a contact, and a mapped contact.  The mapped contact MAY exist, but it may be null.

This is a 0..1:1 mapping, so I've simply added a MappedContactId which has a FK back to the Id of the contacts table.

```
Contact
-----------------------
Id  bigint not-null PK  <----------|
MappedContactId bigint null FK ----|
```

Entity Framework is forcing me to map this as a 1:many relationship.  If I try and map it as a Zero or 1 of Contact, I get the error:

```
Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'MappedContact' in relationship
FK_Contact_MappedContact'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key
properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.
```

Is there any way to get this back to a Zero or 1, or am I stuck with 1:many?